# Where to check the pool stats of FAIR scheduler in Spark Web UI

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I see my Spark application is using FAIR scheduler:

[image]

But I can't confirm whether it is using two pools I set up (pool1, pool2). Here is a thread function I implemented in PySpark which is called twice - one with "pool1" and the other with "pool2".

```
def do_job(f1, f2, id, pool_name, format="json"):
    spark.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", pool_name)
    ...
```

I thought the "Stages" menu is supposed to show the pool info but I don't see it. Does that mean the pools are not set up correctly or am I looking at the wrong place?

[image]

I am using PySpark 3.3.0 on top of EMR 6.9.0

Answer (score 0):

You can confirm  like this diagram.

[pls refer my article I created 3 pools like module1 module2 module3 based on certin logic](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hadoop-yarn-fair-schedular-advantages-explained-part2-ram-ghadiyaram/).
Each one is using specific pool.like above.. based on this I created below diagrams

[image]

Note : Please see the verification steps in the article I gave